# Istio default ingress-gateway got deleted

Tags: istio

I am doing chaos testing on all istio core components, pilot, mixer, citadel, and default objects/resources. It am manually deleting the components and document the behavior, which will help when it actually breaks in production. 
I have deleted ingress-gateway service. It also deleted egress pods, which i didn't expect. 
Since I am going to delete all the default objects one by one, Is there a better or more cleaner way to recreate core objects? For example, how would I recreate ingress and egress services?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the best way to re-create lost/deleted components of Istio, is to do it by helm (package manager for Kubernetes).

```
helm upgrade <your-release-name> <repo-name>/<chart-name> --reuse-values --force
```

You can also keep track of changes of your istio installation (aka Istio release), and simply restore to its last working version using following commands:

```
helm history <release_name>
helm rollback --force [RELEASE] [REVISION]
```

Eventually you can always reach out back to Istio installation directory, and re-apply piece of manifest corresponding to deleted object, for example for istio v1.1.1, the istio-ingressgateway Service object is declared inside 'istio-1.1.1/install/kubernetes/istio-demo.yaml'. Additionally these manifest files can be generated by helm template command directly from [source code](https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/28f2fbbbb0bb4910130b3362cc18c780e1fac87b/Makefile#L651) repository.